# bump API shutdown after 31st January what it's alternate for iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, shake, bump

I am developing the app in which i successfully integrated a bump `API` but recently bump developer site announce that [bump `API` shutdown after 31st January](http://blog.bu.mp/).

Now i wondering about it's alternate way for doing this task in my application to implement without bump `API`.

I just trying use [CPMotionRecognizer](https://codeload.github.com/yangmeyer/CPMotionRecognizer/zip/master) But i didn't know that help's me or not that only detect our device motion while use shake the device. But how to fine near Device that shake with our device like same as Bump API.

Please suggest to me its alternate way or suggestion.

Comment: better to explain for down vote reason then i can more explain with my question.

Comment: Are you using bluetooth functionality for that or involving server side which has the location of every device? I did not down vote.

Comment: I also want to find android device like bump so Bluetooth is not useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a server side involved in your app, you can get the coordinates of every device using CLLocationManager Class and then calculate the distance using following function.

```
#define d2r (M_PI / 180.0)

+(float) haversine_km:(float)lat1: (float)long1: (float)lat2: (float)long2
{
float dlong = (long2 - long1) * d2r;
float dlat = (lat2 - lat1) * d2r;
float a = pow(sin(dlat/2.0), 2) + cos(lat1*d2r) * cos(lat2*d2r) * pow(sin(dlong/2.0), 2); 
float c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
float d = 6367 * c;

return d;
}
```

Where lat1, long1 are the coordinates of first device and lat2, long2 are the coordinates of other device. The result will be in Kilometers and off course you can convert it to your desired unit. Then you can check if it is within your desired range.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the value of d2r variable. The answer is updated now.